# Cannot convert a string using float - Python 3

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, floating-point

I am pretty sure the solution is easy but somehow the usual float doesn't work.

```
output = open('output.txt', 'wt')
with open('input.txt', 'r') as file:
    file = file.readlines()
    for x in range(0,len(file)):
        if file[x][0:6] == 'NUMBER':
            print(file[x][11:18]) 
            float(file[x][11:18])
```

print will give me '11111' ,
but float gives me error ValueError: could not convert string to float: 
What is happening here. I need it as float to do some math operation.

Update. I guess it's because i am trying to convert an empty space. The first line cause this error. float('') will give error.

```
NUMBER
*
NUMBER 111111111111111111111
```

Comment: which language is that? Please tag it

Comment: Thanks guy. Sorry my first time posting.

Comment: The error message on my Python includes the `repr` of the string that it couldn't convert. If that's not printing, try `print(repr(file[x][11:18]))` to see the `repr`. Might be some non-printing character (e.g. `\0`) embedded in the string; `float` ignores leading and trailing whitespace, but not arbitrary non-numeric text or embedded whitespace.

Comment: You can put a `try` and `except` condition to ignore if there is no number in the line

Comment: So what should the value be when the string is empty? Or is the line ignored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A version of the idea that @Bijoy gave in the comments: If the problem is that the string which follows `'NUMBER'` is sometimes empty and such cases should always map to the float `0.0`, you can use error trapping to write a special-purpose version of `float()`:

```
def getfloat(s):
    try:
        return float(s)
    except ValueError:
        return 0.0
```

This will work for your situation, though has the counter-intuitive behavior where e.g. `getfloat("hello world") == 0.0`

Comment: Thank you. This is what I am looking  for.